# Docusign Signature field not showing

Tags: docusignapi

Why is signature field not visible when recipient viewing it.
I have created a template and drag and dropped some text fields and a signature field.Then after save them as Custom fields.
After that under recipients section Role to added "Sender" and Name to added "signer"

I'm using REST APIs to request signature.In my code also I have added RoleName to "signer".

This is worked earlier and one user complete a request after others also can't see the signature.I have created new templates, but them also not showing signature field when viewing in as a recipient.

I think this is a setting changes issue. Please tell me how to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the signature tags and text tags are not referenced correctly for the signer.

Have you tried to create and send envelope using this template through the UI?

As those fields are Signer related, when referencing those fields make sure they go under signer object and are referenced by the correct tabLabel

Will be very helpful if you can provide some code as well

Comment: I have added fields through UI.I can't find a place to specify a signer in the UI.
Now it's showing signer, I have no idea what happened earlier.Anyway thank a lot for your reply

Comment: PLEASE accept / check answer if you think it was answered! THANK YOU!